# JS class property doesnt change as intended

Tags: javascript, class, gsap

I am trying to animate a sprite in a html canvas on button click, deactivate the button until the anim is finished and reactivate it on animation complete, while keeping separate scripts for input handling and animation handling (to improve my coding, no other reason).

I am doing it using

1. a global variable checking if button is pressed
2. a property inside my sprite class checking if the animation is going
3. a function inside my sprite class that animates the sprite with gsap

these are the snippets of code:

1. the button check logic:

it does a querySelectAll, checks, if btn_click is true, it does nothing, if it is false, it returns btn_click to true. this works fine

````
```  let btn_click = false; ```

     document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((btn) => {
           if(btn_click)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else{    
                    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    console.log('click');
                    btn_click = true; 
                    })
                }
         })
````

2. the animation loop:
   inside a requestAnimationFrame, it check: if btn_click is TRUE and if ally_sprite.animation_playing is FALSE, run the animation. This works fine, only once though

function animate_battle() {
window.requestAnimationFrame(animate_battle);

```
if(btn_click)
{
    if(!ally_sprite.animation_playing){
        ally_sprite.attack_anim();
    }
}
```

}

3. And the Sprite class:
   this is the class with its function. The problem is that my onComplete function, runs (the console.log shows correctly and the btn_click gets set to false allowing me to run the previous bit correctly), but does not REALLY set the animation_playing to false. Or at least, if I console log it out INSIDE the onComplete, it turns FALSE, but if I run it outside the variable sticks to TRUE, and so the code above never triggers its if(!ally_sprite.animation_playing)

   ```
       class Sprite{
       constructor({position})
       {
       this.position = {...position}
       this.animation_playing = false;
       }

      attack_anim(){
          const timeline = gsap.timeline()

          this.animation_playing = true;
       timeline.to(this.position, {
                   x: this.position.x - 20, 
               }).to(this.position, {
                   x: this.position.x + 40
               }).to(this.position, {
                   x: this.position.x - 20,
                   onComplete: function() {
                       btn_click = false;
                       this.animation_playing = false; 
                       console.log("completed!");
                   }
               })

               console.log('attacked');    
           }
       }
   ```

It shouldn't be relevant (I believe) but consider that each snippet is stored in a different file: 1 for input_handling, 2 for rendering, 3 for classes.
I know how to solve the matter, by putting everything into one single if statement (by copy-pasting from the code I am reverse engineering), but I would like to understand why my code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround on the rendering class, by changing the animation loop as such:

```
if(btn_click)
{    
    buttons.forEach(btn => {
        btn.disabled = true;
    })

    if(!ally_sprite.animation_playing){
        ally_sprite.attack_anim();
    }
} 
else{
    buttons.forEach(btn => {
        btn.disabled = false;
    })
    ally_sprite.animation_playing = false; 
}
```

this way I get to disable the buttons while the animation is looping, and re-enable them on animation complete, as well as reassigning the ally_sprite.animation_playing

What I still don't understand is why this function is only assigning the external varibles but not the internal property

```
timeline.to(this.position, {
            x: this.position.x - 20,
            onComplete: function() {
                btn_click = false;
                this.animation_playing = false; 
                console.log("completed!");
            }
        })
```

drives me mad!